# C:foreach returns String (Not Object) with JSP2.0

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am getting string objects instead of Person objects in my JSTL.

Here is the code in my .tag file:

```
 <%
List<Person> perList=(List<Person>)pageContext.getAttribute("myVehicles");
 HashMap<String, com.info.PersonInfo> personRatingsMap=(HashMap<String, com.info.PersonInfo>)pageContext.getAttribute("personsMap");
 com.info.PersonInfo rtg=null;
 int i=0;
 HashMap<String, Object> givenMap=null;
 String tempYear=null;

 for(Object obj : perList){
     Person currPer=(Person)obj;
     tempYear=currPer.getYear();
     rtg=personRatingsMap.get(tempYear);
     givenMap=mapValuePair.get(tempYear);
     if(givenMap!=null){
         currPer.getNameset().get("PER").put("fname",givenMap.get("Per_NAME").toString());
         currPer.getNameset().get("PER").put("lname",givenMap.get("PerL_NAME").toString());
         currPer.getIdset().get("PER").put("myid",givenMap.get("myid").toString());
         currPer.setYear(givenMap.get("YEAR").toString());

     }
     if(rtg !=null){
         currPer.setRating(rtg);
     }
     perList.set(i,currPer);
     i++;
 }

 pageContext.setAttribute("myPersons",perList);

%>

<c:forEach items="myPersons" var="perFromList">
    <crp:getModelDefaultPhoto var="defaultPhoto"
    makeid="${perID}" modelid="${perIID}" 
    year="${perFromList.year}" />
<c:if test="${!empty defaultPhoto.value and defaultPhoto.value != ''}"> 
<c:set target="${photomap}" property="${perFromList.year}" value="${defaultPhoto.name},${defaultPhoto.value}" />
</c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

I am getting this error:

> Unable to find a value for "year" in object of class
>   "java.lang.String" using operator "."
>
> Blockquote

So clearly the foreach loop is returning String instead of Person object because when I put System.out.println code in my scriptlet each Peson has the Year associated with it in the foreach It is considering person as String not the Person object.

I will really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
<c:forEach items="${myPersons}" var="perFromList">
```

not

```
<c:forEach items="myPersons" var="perFromList">
```

Without the `${...}`, you're just operating off the String `"myPersons"`, rather than the list that `myPersons` represents.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
<c:forEach items="${myPersons}" var="perFromList">
```